# Play in Production - Secure cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, playframework

I have developed a little program for myself. After testing and 
finishing it locally I now wanted to put it on my server.

I get this error:

> Compilation error  The file /app/controllers/Links.java could not be
>   compiled. Error  raised is : Secure cannot be resolved to a type

It is thrown at this line:

```
@With(Secure.class)
```

In the Class Links I have:

```
   import play.mvc.With; 

   import controllers.*; 

   @With(Secure.class) 

   public class Links extends CRUD { 
   }
```

I have installed play 1.2.2 on my server. Play is running probably. I 
type in the terminal "play start appname" and opened serverIp:9010 to 
see this error. If I type "play precompile appname" everything seems 
to work.

In the subfolder /modules of the app I have two text files, one "crud" 
and one "secure" which point to the modules location on the server. I 
also have defined the modules in dependencies.yml like this:

```
require: 
    - play 
    - crud 
    - secure
```

In the application.conf I have a Production definition for my server 
with the proper Server-ID like this:

```
%server1.application.mode=PROD
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: I also ran "play deps" which had no effect on the problem

Comment: Have you added the modules in `application.conf`?

Comment: @davin no, i have added them in the dependencies.yml file

Comment: mmmm, I'm still in Play! 1.1 world...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it. For future reference:

I had an old process of play running. Found it with `ps -aux` and then `kill PID`. After that I started the application again with `play start`.

It's now running fine :)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I need to wait but I will for others ;)

Answer (score 3):

Declaring the secure module in *dependencies.yml* file is the first step.

Next you have to type the shell command "**play dependencies**" in order to resolve them.

Just have a glance on the documentation here : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/dependency#Theplaydependenciescommand

Have fun with Play!

Comment: I have declared them in the dependencies.yml file and I also ran "play deps", but this had no positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to refesh the classpath settings by using `play eclipsify` again. (depends on the IDE you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert this line to application.config

```
module.secure=${play.path}/modules/secure
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my development environment, but not in my production server. I tried to solve by the module documentation, the accepted answer here, and many others with no success.

My solution was to download again play framework (1.2.7) and replacing it in the path where I installed first.

Hope this can guide someone else with the same issue.

Regards.